# Is there a bamboo task for sleep / wait / timeout?

Tags: timeout, continuous-integration, wait, sleep, bamboo

Is there an easy and working way to achieve a defined waiting period before executing/proceeding to the next stage of a bamboo build plan?

I have tried a "timeout 120" within the script body of an script task in its own stage (bamboo host runs on windows 7). But this was failing.

Comment: Just to let you know. Neither "timeout 120" nor "sleep 120" was working. The only workaround i found was to execute "PING 1.1.1.1 -n 120 >NUL" in the script body via a script task.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 has *sleep* command. Try

```
sleep 120
```

in your script

Comment: A "sleep 120" did not work. As far as i know is the sleep cmd not part of windows 7. sleep --version tells that: sleep (GNU sh-utils).

Answer (score 1):

To add a hard coded wait use ping command. Following is the example with 10 mins wait:

ping 127.255.255.255 -n 10 -w 60000 >NUL

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 6000 >NUL

**Explanation**:

1. 127.255.255.255 = Invalid IP Address which returns time out error

   -n 10 = try pinging 10 times

   -w 60000 = wait for 60 seconds before each try

   NUL = don't save the output

This will always return 1 (failure; since we are not using a ping-able IP address)

2. ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 6000 >NUL
   127.0.0.1 is loopback address and will always return True i.e 0
   Hence your task would Pass and would move to the next task; without using Ping used in step 2 your task would always fail since Step 1 would always fail.

So, step 1 : ensures 10 minutes of wait and step 2 ensures that task gets passed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bamboo powershell task, you can use this cmdlet -

Start-Sleep -s 600

Comment: This is really cool. this worked for me with window power shell,
start-sleep -s 300 => sleep for 5mins